# Python: Use Dropbox API - Save .ODT File

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using Dropbox API with Python. I don't have problems with Dropbox API, I make all the authentification steps without problems.

When I use this code:

```
pdf_dropbox = client.get_file('/Example.pdf')
new_file = open('/home/test.pdf','w')
new_file.write(pdf_dropbox.read())
```

I generate a file in the path `/home/test.pdf`, it's a PDF file and the content is displayed same as original.

But when I try same code with an `.odt` file, it fails generating the new file:

```
odt_dropbox = client.get_file('/Example.odt')
new_file = open('/home/test_odt.odt','w')
new_file.write(odt_dropbox.read())
```

This new file ***test_odt.odt*** has errors and I can't see it's content.

```
# With this instruction I have the content of the odt file inside odt_dropbox
odt_dropbox = client.get_file('/Example.odt')
```

- Wich is the best way to save the content of an `odt` file ?
- Is there a better way to write *LibreOffice* files ?

I'd appreciate any helpfull information,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I forgot 2 things:

1. Open the file for *binary writing* `wb` instead of `w`

   `new_file = open('/home/test_odt.odt','wb')`
2. Close the file after creation: `new_file.close()` to make the flush

**Full Code:**

```
odt_dropbox = client.get_file('/Example.odt')
new_file = open('/home/test_odt.odt','wb')
new_file.write(odt_dropbox.read())
new_file.close()
```

Comment: I think you meant `close` not `save` in your code here. Also, you might want to use a context via `with`. That would be just `with open('/home/test_odt.odt', 'wb') as new_file: new_file.write(odt_dropbox.read())`

Comment: Thanks! I wrote wrong as you said `.save()` instead `.close()`. Now it's fixed. Thanks!